# Azure Default Credential with Managed Identity not working (node)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity, azure-identity

I was trying to use a user-assigned managed identity with the `DefaultAzureCredential`, but am getting the 403 permissions mismatch error. I'm following the code example found in [MS docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/identity/identity/samples/AzureIdentityExamples.md#authenticating-a-service-principal-with-a-client-secret) and it still fails. However, replacing the `DefaultAzureCredential` with the explicit `ManagedIdentityCredential` works just fine.

This is my code:

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');
const {url, clientId} = require('./config');

const cred = new DefaultAzureCredential({managedIdentityClientId: clientId});
const containerClient = new BlobServiceClient(url, cred).getContainerClient('container-name');

(async () => {
  const exists = await containerClient.exists();
  console.log({exists});
})();
```

This looks like it should work, but it does not. Any thoughts?

versions:

- "@azure/identity": "^1.1.0",
- "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.12.0",
- node v16.18.1

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*I tried to reproduce same code in my environment, and it successfully executed with container exist or not.*

**Code:**

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');

const url="https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net";
const clientId="<client-id>";
const cred = new DefaultAzureCredential({managedIdentityClientId: clientId});
const Client = new BlobServiceClient(url, cred);
const containerClient=Client.getContainerClient("test");

(async () => {
  const exists = await containerClient.exists();
  console.log({exists});
})();
```

**Console:**

[image]

> 403, This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

If you are accessing storage account with identity, you need a role like **[Storage-blob-contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal)** or **storage-blob-owner**.

Go to portal -> your storage account -> Access Control (IAM) ->Add -> Add role assignments -> storage-blob-contributor or storage-blob-owner->Add your user managed identity id.

[image]

Also, I tried with user-assigned managed identity with the `DefaultAzureCredential` it worked perfectly.

**Code:**

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');

const url="https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net";
const cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const Client = new BlobServiceClient(url, cred);
const containerClient=Client.getContainerClient("test");

(async () => {
  const exists = await containerClient.exists();
  console.log({exists});
})();
```

**Console:**

[image]

Comment: appreciate you trying this. my permissions are configured correctly as i've been able to use the `ManagedIdentityCredential`. problem only exists with the `DefaultAzureCredential`, meaning it's client-side only. Can you share which version of the packages you're using?

Comment: The version of my packages is **`"@azure/identity": "^3.1.2"`** and  **`"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.12.0"`**.